# How to adjust button width based on screen width in Quartz Designer for iPhone

Tags: ios, quartz-composer, origami

Is there any possibility to adjust button width based on screen width in origami for iPhone, with some expression;

For Example: `button.width = screen.width - 50`

I can't add my current design image to this question due to my low reputation

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this on my own as below;

> Add the following Patches from **Patch Library**

- **Button** Patch
- **Rendering Destination Dimensions** Patch
- **Math** Patch

> Then,

- Link **Pixels Wide** on **Rendering Destination Dimensions** to **first Parameter** on Math Patch
- Modify **Second Parameter** on Math Patch to required value (For Example: 50)
- Select the **-** (Minus) Operator on the Math Patch
- Link **Output** of Math Patch to **Width** on Button Patch